# Why was my Meta question deleted without an answer?

Tags: discussion, support

**Why are we deleting helpful references in this library?**

NO actual *Answer* was provided to be critiqued at all.

https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/explanation-needed-my-account-is-banned-from-asking-questions

Edit:
What is happening as we speak is this.  **The mods are retroactively editing other peoples questions so that they can close my question as a duplicate.** The definition of "duplicate" within the scope of this SE is not well defined allowing loop holes for unbiased moderation.  We discuss our God, bias is inherent here.

The questions I am referencing are these
[Word Study: G5546: Χριστιανός Christianós [duplicate]](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/79314/52004)

This is the **same** one that got me banned from asking any more questions in the linked original question that this question is about...phew

And my new question of the day which was unpopular [According to Trinitarians, Does 1+1+1 = 1? [duplicate]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/93078/60347)

I realize the 2nd link is of a different SE but the members widely overlap including some moderators which is why I am linking in as part  of my premise.

Does it seem odd by any objective person as to why the word Christian is seeing a large resistance to its definition and question in a website devoted to understanding what that means?

**Another** overstep of the moderation's behavior is their unwillingness to close out duplicates of my original question I posed a few days before. And the manipulation of the comments on the duplicate question.

This is my question.
[What happened on the day the son was begotten in Psalm 2?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/79163/52004)

And this is the duplicate.
[Psalms 2:7 meaning before Jesus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79335/psalms-27-meaning-before-jesus)

The duplicate was edited and passed by a single person who is a mod of both BHSE and Christianity SE.  This was the action done instead of closing out the question due to the flag I raised....

This behavior is unbecoming to those who fancy themselves children of God.

Comment: I've removed the comments as I'm hoping that my Answer can resolve this one, and there's no need for further dispute about it all. Apologies for any frustration or confusion caused.

Answer (score 1):

This was just a simple misunderstanding.

As you may recall, yesterday we spent an hour or two on Chat talking through your question/concerns. Eventually I asked:

> "Would you like me to remove your Meta question, if it's been answered already?"

Your next sentence had began with the word "Yes", and so I'd misunderstood that you were happy with the question being removed. I can see now in context that wasn't what you were saying at all. I suppose hermeneutics are important in personal conversations too. :)

As to the "duplicate", it isn't a duplicate at all - just a different question about the same text. You're asking about the meaning of 'begotten', and the other user is asking about the meaning of the entire section before Jesus.

The other user's question is pretty close to *my edit* of your Question which asked whether the intent of the Psalm is different from that of its quotation in Hebrews, but you changed the question back to focus on 'begotten'. It's great that you re-scoped your question back to what you really wanted to ask, but apparently somebody else saw the previous revision and decided to ask a version of that question themselves, or was otherwise inspired by your own reflections.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  That makes a lot of sense.  I'm still banned from asking questions. 
My focus is not on begotten.  The subject is that "day".  I specified begotten because its specified in the scriptures.

Comment: No problem @ReadLessPrayMore - your question is 'what happened on the day the son was begotten', and in the text you highlighted the word **begotten**, so at a cursory read I'd have probably assumed that was the word you were focusing on, though I know previous iterations of it had a clearer focus on **day**.

Comment: I'm glad we were able to rescue that first Question then, that's a success story right there, +4 is a good result! If you can do the same for one or two of the others that are negatively voted or Closed it should release the Question ban.

Comment: I also can't flag any questions any longer.  I would like to chat with an admin as to why some of my flags were denied.  I would like to understand what qualifies a duplicate.  The Psalms 2 duplicate example....My scope completely envelopes every answer her question could possibly have.

Comment: The psalms 2 duplicate is asking for an interpretation of that verse before Jesus walked the geocentric earth.  Has the interpretation changed?  It was prophetic either way.

Comment: There does tend to be something of a Christian bias in responses, many users would immediately read the verse in relation to Jesus, perhaps linking it to Hebrews as your earlier revision did. But this user clearly wants to explore pre-Christian readings of the text. You're both creating different questions by scoping down tightly on one aspect - for you you're wanting to explore the meaning of the word *day*, and for the other they're wanting to explore the whole verse's pre-Christian reading. Those are two different questions.

Comment: You'll find existing questions about just about every passage in the Bible, especially those of messianic, prophetic or doctrinal interest. Often the art of creating new and distinct questions is about scoping in tightly on one aspect of the text to explore an area that other questions haven't. But you've rightly touched on a very challenging area of site moderation - distinguishing a duplicate between two similar questions is hard! It's not unusual for a Question to be Closed as Duplicate, but then to be justified as a unique question or re-scoped until it is opened again.

Comment: Can you provide me one possible answer where the ven diagram of the answers of both our  questions would NOT look like a donut?  Its not hard.  JUst make rules and stick to them.  This is one rule I thought defined a duplicate. Overlapping scopes and possible answers.

Comment: Well given that you had tagged your original question 'trinity', I can only imagine that you were hoping for answers to get to the root of the Day, what it means for the son to be *begotten* on it, and what the text means in that respect. Whereas the other question is specifically about exploring pre-Christian views on the text. If a week or two passes and it becomes plain that based on the Answers they are obvious duplicates, we may choose to Close the other one as a duplicate and merge it in. Sometimes you just have to give new Questions the benefit of the doubt if they *might* be unique.

Comment: The other question is scoped to a specific viewpoint.

Comment: Just about. More specifically, it's scoped to a point in time. **Most often** the key thing is understanding the *authorial intent* or how a text would be understood by its first recipients. So typically a good question will focus on that. Usually we don't like questions to require a certain type of viewpoint in the Answer, but requiring it to be authentic to the time of the text is fair game.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Sometimes we do get questions along the lines of "what are the arguments for X position on this text" and that would be the main exception to what I've just described.

Comment: And IN the time since then, what has happened to change the interpretation over time?  Its prophetic.  So in this case the scope of time is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, Jesus came, for a start. Many other texts were written, which may be taken as evidence of how later recipients understood it, or could be a new slant on the text. Hebrews has a few examples where it blatantly takes a text out of its original intended context and takes it to mean something new.

Comment: For many OT texts they would be understood in a different way by their original recipients, vs later recipients (perhaps post-Exile), vs later Jewish perspectives, vs early Christian viewpoints, etc. For just about every biblical passage there are different interpretations that have been preferred at different points in history, and sometimes the scriptures themselves interpret a single passage in different ways.

Comment: Jesus' birth didn't change the interpretation of that scripture.  Only for a scoped perspective which is OFF TOPIC 100%

Comment: Have you read the Dead Sea Scrolls? There are so many different views of who the Messiah would be based on the OT. The War Scroll is particularly distinctive, and is very different from later interpretations following the fall of Jerusalem. The whole NT is a reinterpretation of messianic texts - new interpretations that had not been envisaged before. That's why Jesus' teaching was so shocking to many.

Comment: What does that have to do with the duplicate question with a scoped perspective?  FWIW...I have not read them yet.  I'm still digesting the solid food of the bible.

Comment: Well you're suggesting that prophetic texts are immutable and that interpretations don't change after later events pass, and I'm explaining that's not always the case. Throughout the Bible passages are reinterpreted time and time again, and so it's okay for a historic interpretation to be different from one that comes later after more or different information is available to readers/hearers.

Comment: Besides, most likely the original interpretation wouldn't have perceived the text as 'prophetic' at all - it's a Psalm, a song about events of the present or past. It likely got reinterpreted as 'messianic' post Exile, and then interpreted again in light of Jesus.

Comment: We've got enough chats open, I'm not opening a third one - locking comments on this post